# Is there a way to add actions to a context menu for an LPLinkView rich link preview?

Tags: swift

When I long press an LPLinkView view https://developer.apple.com/documentation/linkpresentation/lplinkview, the standard context menu actions show up.  Is there any way I can add to this array of actions?

[image]

*For context on rich links, the screen capture I pasted in the original question was from an example app which you can run: https://github.com/alfianlosari/iOSVisualRichLinkApp*